# Allow using arrow keys to move hats more precisely

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

During this Winter Bash, I've been trying to move one of my hats to the *perfect* location on top of my avatar, but the mouse is not letting me position it correctly.

It would be helpful if support could be added for arrow keys. This would make it easier to do precise movements ("nudges") of a hat.

Comment: Why not just zoom in? Same mouse movement == smaller screen movement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No time for it this year, so declining right now. Possible for a future Winter Bash iteration.